Не работает авторизация через телеграмм на сайте
<script async="" src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?2" data-telegram-login="TestTelegram555Bot" data-size="large" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" data-request-access="write"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onTelegramAuth(user) {
        alert('Logged in as ' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ' (' + user.id + (user.username ? ', @' + user.username : '') + ')');
        }
</script>

При попытке авторизации alert не отображается. В чем проявляется проблема? Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы
